# Why is my Visual Studio Cloud Project recursively nesting its package in my Web role build output?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure, cloud

I have a pretty simple Could Project (named Uploader.Cloud) with one Web Role (UploaderWebRole) and I'm trying to build them using visual studio.  I've modified the project files of both of these projects to change their output path to a different place than the default spot.  What I'm finding is that I'm getting a MSB3021 build error when I build Uploader.Cloud:

```
Unable to copy file "D:\Enlistments\FB1\Dev\Izer\Build\Release\Cloud\Uploader.Cloud.csx\roles\LogUploaderWebRole\approot\bin\Uploader.Cloud.csx\roles\LogUploaderWebRole\approot\bin\_PublishedWebsites\UploaderWebRole\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll" 
to "D:\Enlistments\FB1\Dev\Izer\Logging\Uploader.Cloud\obj\Release\LogUploaderWebRole\bin\Uploader.Cloud.csx\roles\LogUploaderWebRole\approot\bin\Uploader.Cloud.csx\roles\LogUploaderWebRole\approot\bin\_PublishedWebsites\UploaderWebRole\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll". 
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. 
The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Upon further inspection, I find it odd that the bin folder of my web role (**LogUploaderWebRole\approot\bin**) has a cloud package in it (**Uploader.Cloud.csx**).  I don't think that should be the case and am curious if this is a bug in my configuration or if there's a bug in how Visual Studio's Azure tools are building my project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You say you modified both project files, what exactly were the modifications, there may be a clue in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  I modified the OutputPaths of the Uploader.Cloud and LogUploaderWebRole projects to build to a different spot.  On top of that, Uploader.Cloud was using a web role named LogUploaderWebRole, but the project was named UploaderWebRole.  Replacing all instances of LogUploaderWebRole with UploaderWebRole in both projects fixed the issue.  For some reason, having the different names caused the build process to nest Uploader.Cloud.csx in multiple levels of the build directory hierarchy.